# Reeborg's World Around 1 - Variable (Python's While Loop)

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to programming and I'm trying my hand at Reeborg's World https://reeborg.ca/reeborg.html problems. However, I've reached a block at Around 1 - Variable.

This is my code right now:

```
def walk():
    if wall_on_right()==True and wall_in_front()==False:
        move()
    if wall_in_front()==True:
        turn_left()
        move()

put("token")
move()
while object_here("token")!=True:
    walk()
if object_here("token")==True:
    done()
```

The problem is that it creates an infinite loop. It seems that the while function is not recognizing the token put at the starting position as a the condition that breaks out of the loop.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use `if elif else` condition to move next step. this problem cant be help much as needed more info

Answer (score 0):

```
def turn_right():
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
def jump():
    move()
    turn_left()
    move()
    turn_right()
    move()
    turn_right()
    move()
    turn_left()
        
def turn_up():
    turn_left()
    move()
    turn_right()
    move()
    turn_right()
    move()
    turn_left()
        

#for steps in range (0, 5):
    #jump()
#hurdle = 6
while at_goal() != True:
    
    if wall_in_front() == True:
        turn_up()
    elif front_is_clear() == True:
        move()
    

    
This is how I solved mine for puzzle 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It is most helpful to the original post, though, if you can provide some narrative text along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finished the same exercise:

```
put()

while not wall_in_front():
    move()
    if wall_in_front():
        turn_left()
    elif object_here():
        done()
```

Basically:

- It moves straight while there is not wall in the front and it keeps checks with a while loop if there is wall or not in front.
- If there is a wall it turns left and gets in while loop again.
- To stop the while loop; to determine the starting point first I left a token with `put()` function. With an `elif` statement after `if` statement I have used `object_here()` function so it can detect the object and stop the while loop with `done()` function.

If anyone has an better solution for that I'd love to see different approaches.

Answer (score -1):

I fiddled a little more on this problem and found a way to solve it

```
def walk():
    while wall_on_right() and not wall_in_front():
        if object_here():
            take()
            done()
        else:
            move()
def turn():
    while wall_on_right() and wall_in_front():
        turn_left()
        move()
put("token")
move()

while True:
    walk()
    turn()
```

The problem mostly consists of how I was understanding the `object_here ()`
function since, as mentioned in their page "Reeborg can determine whether or not there is at least one object at his location". Therefore, adding a `take ()` and
`done ()` function in case Reeborg detected an object in a given field was able to do the trick.